# Detect change in array element by element

Tags: c++, arduino

I am unable to determine the differences of elements in two arrays having digital data of 8-bits.

I want to write code which should return me which element of the second array is changed and what's the updated value of same element in second array?

Here is the code which I have done:

```
int c, i;
int b[8];
int d[8];
int x[8];

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    for(i=0; i<8; i++){
        d[i] = bitRead(0,i);
    }
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    c = random(255);
    for (i=0; i<8; i++){
        b[i] = bitRead(c,i);
        // Serial.print(b[i]);
    }

    for (i=0; i<8; i++){
        x[i] = check(b[i],d[i]);
    }

    for (i=0; i<8; i++){  
        Serial.print(x[i]);
    }

    Serial.println();

    for(i=0; i<8; i++){
        d[i] = b[i];
        //Serial.print(d[i]);
    }
    Serial.println();

    delay(1000);
}

int check(int x[], int y[]){
    if(x!=y){
        return i;    
    } else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int check(int x[], int y[]){
    if(x!=y){
        return i;    
    } else {

    }
}
```

First in this function you don't have `i` variable. You wait for two arrays in entry, but when you call this function you pass only integers. Then all path of the function doesn't return value.

What you should try is to make the `x` table as boolean table and then remove your check function to do something like :

```
for (i=0; i<8; i++){
    x[i] = (b[i]==d[i]);
}
```

You will get a table where value at the index `i` is true where the value of `b[i]` and `d[i]` is the same.

Comment: Sorry i didnt got you

Comment: for (i=0; i<8; i++){
                x[i] = check(b[i],d[i]);
            }                                                                                                               
 when i am calling a fuction i am passing two variables b and d and my function is only returning one variable, and please elaborate further what this does                                                                          
     for (i=0; i<8; i++){
        x[i] = (b[i]==d[i]);
    }

Comment: In your check function if x==y you don't return any value.(b[i]==d[i]) is a boolean expression : result is always true or false. True when the values are the same and false otherwise.

Comment: so you mean x[i]=(b[i]==d[i]) would return me the boolean values for every index

Comment: what if i want to know what is the updated variable only and ignore the ones who are same

Comment: I mean that it would return the after the for loop, x is a array of 8 boolean values. x[i] == true only if b[i]==d[i] otherwise x[i] == false.